# JQuery Blur How to Get Current Control ID

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, blur

I have a GridView of ASP.NET with Template Field containing textbox.

A javascript code calling ajax to validate the user input is correct or not. I wish to detect this by the cursor leaves the textbox, which seems like JQuery.Blur will do.

The question is: how to get the control ID that the cursor blur from?

Comment: Could you please add some code? If you're trying to get the id inside an event handler then use `this.id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
$('.selector').blur(function() {
   var blurId = this.id;
   // do something with the id
   ...       
   alert('Control that triggered blur was ' + blurId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add a class to the textbox so you can identify those textboxes around your GridView.

2) When you finish render your GridView (in case is a full load of page, or ajax call), add an event handler to these classes s they trigger the blur event, like this:

```
$('.myTextboxThatShouldBeValidated').blur(function(){
   var myControlID = $(this).attr("id");
   yourAjaxCallValidation(myControlID);
});
```

3) Done!